# How to export a CSV file c# program to a text file the in order to view the changes

Tags: c#, csv

I have successfully imported a CSV file into my solution(C#) and implemented some changes on the file. I can view the changes when i run the console application program. However i do not know how to view the new updated file outside the console application program. i  preferably  would like to export the updated file to excel and view the data or transform the CSVfile to a text file.

Any suggestions on how to do this process would be appreciate it.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "InventoryReport 02_08_2016.csv");
        var fileContents = ReadFile(filePath);
        foreach (var line in fileContents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static IList<string> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            // Skip the line with column names
            if (i == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Splitting by space. I assume this is the pattern
            var replace = lines[i].Replace(' ', ',');

            results.Add(replace);
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you loading the file into the program? is it simply as text? show some code!

Comment: i have updated my question with some code.

Comment: any reason not to simply use File.WriteAllText or File.WriteAllLines?

Comment: Used this current method to just real the file row and apply changes to only one column only

Comment: tried this solution? [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26403750/Convert-transform-csv-into-txt-file-using-net-C.html)

Answer (score 0):

To parse a csv is a non-trivial task. Think for example on quoting quotes within strings. There are some libraries, but these do not work very nice, you will end up improving these yourself. Look for example at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302293.aspx
 Chris Lovett, Software Architect, WebData team, Microsoft Corporation
 March 2002 (Revised February 2004)
  download: https://xmlcsvreader.codeplex.com/ history: 12 Jan 2013

To create a new CSV, you need to code the entire structure of the csv yourself. Here is for example how to format some common fields:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the string to a CSV field,
    /// enclosed in quotes to protect comma's in the field,
    /// with the quotes in the field escaped,
    /// and the separation value added
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Field"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string CsvField(string Field)
    {
        //const string CsvDelim = ",";
        const string Quote = "\"";
        const string Quotes2 = "\"\"";
        string F = "";
        if (Field != null)
        {
            Field = CsvProcessNewline(Field);
            F = string.Format("{0}{1}{0}", Quote, Field.Replace(Quote, Quotes2));
        }
        return F;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the number to a CSV field,
    /// enclosed in quotes to protect comma's in the field,
    /// with the quotes in the field escaped,
    /// and the separation value added
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Field"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string CsvField(int Field)
    {
        return CsvField(string.Format("{0}", Field));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert the date to a CSV field
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Field"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string CsvField_Date(DateTime Field)
    {
        return CsvField(string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss}", Field));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Newlines in a quoted CSV text field should not be a problem,
    /// but some systems can only handle this if CR+LF is replaced by CR or LF.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Field"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string CsvProcessNewline(string Field)
    {
        const string NL = "\n";
        //const string CR = "\r";
        const string CRNL = "\r\n";
        const string NLCR = "\n\r";
        Field = Field.Replace(CRNL, NL);
        Field = Field.Replace(NLCR, NL);
        return Field;
    }
```